# How do I return and print out the starting address of the first string (string1)?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strcpy, function-declaration

I first copy the second string into the first string. Then I would return string1 pointer from the function. Then I use 
**%p and (void*)** 
to print out the starting address of the first string. Is this the right approach?

```
    printf("address: %p  \n", (void*)functionstrcpy(stringnumber1,stringnumber 2));
    return 0;
}

char *functionstrcpy(char *stringnumber1,char *stringnumber2)
{
    //calculation
    return stringnumber1;
}
```

Comment: `int length2 = strlen(str2);
    
    for(i = 0; i < length2; i ++ )` runs down `str2` twice.  `for(i = 0; str2[i]; i ++ )` only once.  Both are _right_, the 2nd likely faster.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I saw my friend wrote like that. But I am not familiar with this so I didn't try that way lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return and print out the .... address of the ... string?
>   I use `"%p"` and `(void*)` to print out the starting address of the first string. Is this the right approach?

Yes. The return is correct and `"%p"` expects to match a `void *`.  Yet since `char *` and `void *` are the same encoding and size, either will work.

```
printf("address: %p  \n", (void*)functionstrcpy(str1,str2));
// or 
printf("address: %p  \n",        functionstrcpy(str1,str2));
```

Thus the choice is best according to your group's style guide.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration should look like

```
char * functionstrcpy( char *str1, const char *str2 );
```

As you are using already the standard C function `strlen` then why not to use another string function `strcpy`? In this case the function can be just a wrapper for the function `strcpy` without any additional functionality.

```
char * functionstrcpy( char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    return strcpy( str1, str2 );
}
```

If you want to write the function yourself without using the standard C function `strcpy` then its definition can look like

```
char * functionstrcpy( char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    for ( char *p = str1; ( *p++ = *str2++ ); );

    return str1;
}
```

You may use the returned pointer in the call of `printf` like

```
printf("address: %p  \n", (void*)functionstrcpy(str1,str2));
```

because you are just outputting the value of a valid pointer.